# Color gradient changing with surface curvature

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials

I am wondering how to make a color gradient following the changes of curvature of a surface. The trick is, I would like the color gradient to only follow the changes of curvature along z, like in the image I post here. [image]

Thank you for your help!

Gaël

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the normal output from the "Texture Coordinate" node, then extract the z value. A value of 0 means the normal is orthogonal to the vertical axis, a value of 1 means the face is horizontal, facing up, and a value of -1 means the face is horizontal, facing down.

Shade smooth, shade flat, and wireframe in [-1;1] :

[image]

Shade smooth, shade flat, and wireframe in absolute [0;1] mode :

[image]

As pointed out in the comments by @Robin Betts, this will give you the normal in local space. It means if you rotate your object, but don't apply the transform, the color of each face will stay the same. If you want your shading to be applied in world space, you should use the normal output from the "Geometry" node.

Illustration :

[image]

Top row : World space, using the "Geometry" node

Bottom row : Object space, using the "Texture coordinate" node.

Rotation is not applied in both rows.

[image]

Comment: This is in Object Space... maybe @Gael wants it in World Space (Geometry>Normal)? Prob. no difference here...

Comment: @RobinBetts Alright ! Thanks, that slipped my mind :)

Comment: That is wonderful, exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much! :)